# How seriously busy is Seville during the holy week?

Tags: spain, seville

I understand it is very busy, on a scale of 1 to 10, is it a 11 or a 12 or a 20 ?

How difficult will it be for regular tourists (2 70-ish, 3 late 40-ish and a 13 y.o. teen) to do their things (visit the Cathedral, Real Alcazar…) and eat during the day and in the evening ?

After further reading (comments here and linked web sites), we have decided to try the week before ( those were the only 2 weeks we can do it).

Maybe close this question?

Comment: I will keep the second question as it is related to the first one;

Comment: That is why I am asking. I thought some processions were done "around" parishes in the city.

Comment: You are explicitly asking for an evaluation on a deliberately non-fixed scale. Those have to be opinion based! - So, if "10" is Masjid al-Ḥarām during Hajj, then what is 11, 12 or 20?

Comment: It doesn't look like the good moment to go. From [Explore Seville: Semana Santa in Seville](http://www.exploreseville.com/events/semana-santa.htm): _Do be ready for some of the biggest crowds you've ever seen as well as some pushing_.

Comment: Unless you are going specifically for the processions, avoid those dates. It will be crowded, and also the passing of processions will make moving through the city difficult.